# firebase deploy not deploying functions to Firebase project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy my cloud functions to a firebase project but I get an error in the debug log. I'm not sure which "error" line is the problem.

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   '--prefix',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Nate Kane\\AndroidStudioProjects\\tonnah\\functions',
0 verbose cli   'run',
0 verbose cli   'lint'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.4.3
2 info using node@v15.7.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Nate Kane\AndroidStudioProjects\tonnah\functions\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Nate Kane\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Nate Kane\AndroidStudioProjects\tonnah\functions\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 10ms
19 verbose npm-session 667279f9488ba0d6
20 timing npm:load Completed in 26ms
21 timing command:run-script Completed in 1104ms
**22 verbose stack Error: command failed**
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:379:20)
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1069:16)
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:300:5)
23 verbose cwd C:\Users\Nate Kane\AndroidStudioProjects\tonnah
24 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
25 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--prefix" "C:\\Users\\Nate Kane\\AndroidStudioProjects\\tonnah\\functions" "run" "lint"
26 verbose node v15.7.0
27 verbose npm  v7.4.3
**28 error code 1
29 error path C:\Users\Nate Kane\AndroidStudioProjects\tonnah\functions
30 error command failed
31 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c eslint .**
32 verbose exit 1
```

I need help fixing this because I don't know why it is failing. I have high lighted the errors in the debug output.

Comment: Could you please share your function that are you trying to deploy?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I fixed this by blowing away my pc and starting over. Now it works. It must have been an environment issue.